# Solr Data Import Handler (DIH) - MySQL Import Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, solr

I have a MySQL database with 4 million products, which I am importing into Solr using DIH so that I may perform elaborate searches. However the data relationships mean that I actually request a lot more than four million records (e.g. one product may have many colours, etc), and it takes over 8 hours to build the index.

Is there a way to improve the performance of the indexing without using delta-queries? For example, is the performance bottleneck due to the multiple "join" conditions I am using? There are no indexing performance statistics available in Solr that I can see so it is very hard to diagnose where the performance bottleneck is.

This is my data-config.xml file:

Thanks,

```
<document>
    <entity name="A" pk="id" query="SELECT id AS id_productByStore, id_product, id_store, ... FROM A">
        <entity name="B" pk="id" query="SELECT id, cleanTitle, id_brand, ... FROM B WHERE id='${A.id_product}'">
            <entity name="C" pk="id" query="SELECT name, alias FROM C WHERE id ='${B.id_brand}'"></entity>
            <entity name="D" pk="id" query="SELECT name FROM D WHERE id ='${B.id_category}'"></entity>
            <entity name="E" pk="id" query="SELECT gender FROM E WHERE id='${B.id_gender}'" > </entity>
            <entity name="F" pk="id" query="SELECT id_colour FROM F WHERE id_colourSet='${B.id_colourSet}'">
                <entity name="G" pk="id" query="SELECT title FROM G WHERE id='${F.id_colour}'" > </entity>
            </entity>
        </entity>
        <entity name="H" pk="id" query="SELECT name FROM H WHERE id = '${A.id_store}'"></entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your MySQL DB and Solr server are not on the same machine, you could have a network issue on your hands. The DB and Solr server at my shop aren't on the same machine and sometimes imports slow down by a lot, depending on what's going on that day.

The thing that is probably your biggest contributor is your nested entities. When Solr imports documents, it appears that Solr behaves as if nested entities are nested loops. You would probably be *much* better off if you could use a series of inner or right joins to bring your columns together in one query.

We used to use nested entities where I work, and imports could take hours. We were able to write a fairly complex MySQL join to replace those nested entities. Our full imports typically are around the 10 - 15 minute range, and we're pulling in about 3 or 4 million records. Deltas are in the 5 - 10 minute range. Even if you can't join all your columns, joining as many as possible and using nested entities for the rest should help your indexing time.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. If I use a join in my scenario, where it is a one-to-many relationship, I will naturally have repeating data - will Solr be able to cope with this?

Comment: As long as the unique key (defined in your schema.xml) for each document is truly unique, it won't be a problem. I had to move to using an automatically-generated UUID in the schema because I had duplicated ids. If the ids are duplicates, the documents with those ids won't be added to the index. They'll be listed as "deleted" on the Solr Admin UI.

Comment: Thank you, we have gone from 8 hours down to 30 minutes. Brilliant! We do appear to have an issue with the one-to-many relationship however. We are only getting one row of the "many" for each record.

Comment: That might be the duplicate id issue I mentioned earlier. You may need to use a composite id or a uuid as a uniqueKey for your documents. If, on full import, Solr is processing all the documents you expect it to, but not all of them are added to the index, check your core's Overview page to see if there are deletedDocs. If so, you'll need to find another uniqueKey.

Comment: You should look into using Views as well as views happen to be a nice alternative to the nested entities. The nested entities feature of DIH is pretty much un-usable at this point due to inefficiency.